# libreoffice calc if 2 columns contain match show third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Columns are ID_AllOrders, Date_AllOrders, and ID_CertainOrders.

I need a 4th column for Date_Certain orders by grabbing the Date_AllOrders for each ID_CertainOrders that matches a row in ID_AllOrders.

I'm using libreoffice calc and been trying tutorials for for INDEX + MATCH but only getting errors so far.

For INDEX I'm using the ID_AllOrders column and for MATCH I'm using the ID_CertainOrders column and looking in the array of all columns.

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$17143, MATCH(F2,$A$2:$D$17143))
```

Is INDEX + MATCH what I need?

Does it matter if the Date column is a timestamp like 2022-03-06 10:47:17 -0500?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense "ID_CertainOrders that matches a row in ID_CertainOrders." don't you mean IDAllOrders?

Comment: @retiredgeek Thanks for catching my mistake. I edited the question. I was able to get the data by using a VLOOKUP formula. I'll post that as an answer but am sill wondering if there's a way to do it with INDEX + MATCH.

Comment: IMHO I always prefer VLookup to Index+Match, it's much simpler and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get what I needed with INDEX + MATCH. If there is one, I'd love to see it.

However, I did find a solution using VLOOKUP...

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$17143,4,0)
```

F2 is the top cell in the column of CertainIDs I want to find. The range is all the rows and columns including AllIDs and DATES. The "4" means the AllDates column is "D" and the "0" means I want the AllId and the CertainID to be an exact match.